# How good is the layout android design for this case?

Tags: android, layout

I have a design with header and footer (not fixed) scrolling with a content that is longer than the height of the screen.
Question 1. When I click the button on screen 1, content 1 will be replaced by content 2. footer and header remain the same.
Question 2. header and footer both have their own events, how can I reuse those events and only write code once?

Design what Views and View groups are suitable for this case, please help me. Currently I use Scrollview as container then replace content 1 with frament containing content 2.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

ViewPager may be good for you. You can define 2 sub pages for the view pager, and when button on page 1 is clicked, advance the view pager to the next page.